# INSERT values with random values defined in front of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, default

how can we insert default value like below ?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, number = rand())
VALUES ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3'), ('name4')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change/add the existing `default` constraint and perhaps revert it afterwards if it was only meant to be temporarily:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT def_number DEFAULT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) FOR number;
```

and now you can insert them like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name)
VALUES ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3'), ('name4')
```

For example, this

```
drop table table1;
create table table1 (name varchar(50), number int);
alter table table1 add constraint def_number default abs(checksum(newid())) for number;
insert into table1 (name) values ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3'), ('name4');
select * from table1;
```

will produce

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what aspect of the question you are having trouble with and whether by "default" value you mean "default" in the specific way that SQL Server uses the term.

Assuming that you want four *different* random number values on the four inserted rows, the easiest way to do what you want is four separate `insert` statements.  Personally, I prefer the `insert . . . select` syntax to `insert . . . values` because it is more flexible:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, number)
    SELECT 'name1', rand();

INSERT INTO table (name, number)
    SELECT 'name2', rand();

INSERT INTO table (name, number)
    SELECT 'name3', rand();

INSERT INTO table (name, number)
    SELECT 'name4', rand();
```

In SQL Server, if you put these into one statement, `rand()` is evaluated only once so all four rows will get the same value.  A typical way around that is to use `checksum(newid())` or `rand(checksum(newid()))` for the random number generation.  If so, this will work:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, number)
    SELECT 'name1', rand(checksum(newid())) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'name2', rand(checksum(newid())) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'name3', rand(checksum(newid())) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'name4', rand(checksum(newid()));
```

You can also use similar logic to set up a default value for the column.  If you want the "random" number to be tied to the name, then you can use:  `name` rather than `newid()` in the expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO demoSO (NAME, number)
VALUES ('name1',RAND()), ('name2',RAND()), ('name3',RAND()), ('name4',RAND())
```